# GWT + IntelliJ Idea - adding a server side library

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt, intellij-idea

I am trying to implement a GWT project in IntelliJ Idea 15. I have no problems (at least obvious) with GWT and its superdev mode - I can run an application and play with it. I can do RPC calls.

However, now I am trying to add JPA/Hibernate support to use a database. And here I have troubles. In the project I have a GWT facet (2.6.1), a JPA facet (with hibernate implementation), and a web facet (for web dd). Using `Open Module Settings -> Libraries -> New Project Library` I have added `gwt-servlet.jar`, and using maven (its not a maven project, just using the feature of Idea) libraries: `c3p0:c3p0:0.9.1.2`, `org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.0.3.Final`, `org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41` ; that is the configuration.

Using this persistence unit properties (excerpt):

```
                <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>

                <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
                <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
                <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300" />
                <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
                <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000" />
```

In GWT RPC servlet I try to create EntityManager instance:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ThreatPersistenceUnit");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Asset a");
...
```

But when I try to run it in the IDEA using default GWT run configuration (Jetty), I get following exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
```

caused by

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.postgresql.Driver
```

Also, before the exception I get following warning:
    WARN: HHH000022: c3p0 properties were encountered, but the c3p0 provider class was not found on the classpath; these properties are going to be ignored.

So it seems the server cannot see both c3p0 and postgre jdbc driver.

I tried to google, the closest problem/solution I found is this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078773/jetty-intellij-idea-add-library).  I have put the libraries both to the project and to the artifact. However, I am not sure what the replier meant by the Jetty lib. Where would I find Jetty installation, if I am using just the GWT's default server?

Plus, what seems quite weird to me is that before I had a similar problem (I dont remember if it was exactly the ClassNotFoundException) with GWT RPC that I was able to resolve by adding a gwt-servlet.jar to the libraries - why then adding these other libraries does not help? At least it seems that it does not have any problems with hibernate, since it provides the warnings and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, even though it is a stupid mistake, maybe someday in the future someone else will make it, so for future reference this was the issue:

I had set the SDK and sources version of the project as 1.6; the hibernate and other libraries seem to been compiled in the same or lower version. However, the postgre driver was compiled using a newer version - when I have set the source version to 1.7 and set as an SDK the Java 8 SDK, the program crashed at some different exception (but that was due to my programming error - unrelated). I found this out only after I tried (in total desperation) to create a new object of the driver manually in the code (not to delegate the creation to persistence provider) - then I got the major minor version exception and I knew what is the problem.